# Mysql Cluster Disk Storage Problem

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster, ndbcluster

We are currently create a Mysql Cluster with ndb distribution storage. We have a very large set of data so we want to config the ndb using the tablespace to store data in disk. 
I follow this link to config the tablespace and I check the ndb instance and I can see the data file is created.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-cluster-disk-data-objects.html

```
CREATE LOGFILE GROUP lg_1
    ADD UNDOFILE 'undo_1.log'
    INITIAL_SIZE 1M
    UNDO_BUFFER_SIZE 2M
    ENGINE NDBCLUSTER;

ALTER LOGFILE GROUP lg_1
    ADD UNDOFILE 'undo_2.log'
    INITIAL_SIZE 1M
    ENGINE NDBCLUSTER;

ALTER LOGFILE GROUP lg_1
    ADD UNDOFILE 'undo_3.log'
    INITIAL_SIZE 1M
    ENGINE NDBCLUSTER;

CREATE TABLESPACE ts_1
    ADD DATAFILE 'data_1.dat'
    USE LOGFILE GROUP lg_1
    INITIAL_SIZE 5G
    ENGINE NDBCLUSTER;

ALTER TABLESPACE ts_1
    ADD DATAFILE 'data_2.dat'
    INITIAL_SIZE 5G
    ENGINE NDBCLUSTER;

ALTER TABLESPACE ts_1
    ADD DATAFILE 'data_3.dat'
    INITIAL_SIZE 5G
    ENGINE NDBCLUSTER;

ALTER TABLESPACE ts_1
    ADD DATAFILE 'data_4.dat'
    INITIAL_SIZE 5G
    ENGINE NDBCLUSTER;

ALTER TABLESPACE ts_1
    ADD DATAFILE 'data_5.dat'
    INITIAL_SIZE 5G
    ENGINE NDBCLUSTER;

ALTER TABLESPACE ts_1
    ADD DATAFILE 'data_6.dat'
    INITIAL_SIZE 5G
    ENGINE NDBCLUSTER;

ALTER TABLESPACE ts_1
    ADD DATAFILE 'data_7.dat'
    INITIAL_SIZE 5G
    ENGINE NDBCLUSTER;

ALTER TABLESPACE ts_1
    ADD DATAFILE 'data_8.dat'
    INITIAL_SIZE 5G
    ENGINE NDBCLUSTER;
```

Then I create all table and I alter them to use the tablespace.

```
alter table AggregateNodeData TABLESPACE ts_1 STORAGE DISK;
alter table AlertEvent TABLESPACE ts_1 STORAGE DISK;
alter table AlertProfile TABLESPACE ts_1 STORAGE DISK;
alter table AreaType TABLESPACE ts_1 STORAGE DISK;
alter table BatteryReading TABLESPACE ts_1 STORAGE DISK;
alter table Building TABLESPACE ts_1 STORAGE DISK;
alter table CalculationRule TABLESPACE ts_1 STORAGE DISK;
alter table City TABLESPACE ts_1 STORAGE DISK;
alter table Country TABLESPACE ts_1 STORAGE DISK;
alter table Gateway TABLESPACE ts_1 STORAGE DISK;
alter table GatewayMapping TABLESPACE ts_1 STORAGE DISK;
alter table HistoryChange TABLESPACE ts_1 STORAGE DISK;
alter table HistoryRecord TABLESPACE ts_1 STORAGE DISK;
alter table HistoryRecordDetails TABLESPACE ts_1 STORAGE DISK;
alter table Log TABLESPACE ts_1 STORAGE DISK;
alter table LogDetails TABLESPACE ts_1 STORAGE DISK;
alter table Node TABLESPACE ts_1 STORAGE DISK;
alter table NodeData TABLESPACE ts_1 STORAGE DISK;
alter table Notification TABLESPACE ts_1 STORAGE DISK;
alter table NotificationTimetable TABLESPACE ts_1 STORAGE DISK;
alter table Organization TABLESPACE ts_1 STORAGE DISK;
alter table Point TABLESPACE ts_1 STORAGE DISK;
alter table PointAlertProfile TABLESPACE ts_1 STORAGE DISK;
alter table PointAlertStatus TABLESPACE ts_1 STORAGE DISK;
alter table PointData TABLESPACE ts_1 STORAGE DISK;
alter table PointSensor TABLESPACE ts_1 STORAGE DISK;
alter table PointType TABLESPACE ts_1 STORAGE DISK;
alter table RawData TABLESPACE ts_1 STORAGE DISK;
alter table Role TABLESPACE ts_1 STORAGE DISK;
alter table RoleFunction TABLESPACE ts_1 STORAGE DISK;
alter table RoleFunctionMapping TABLESPACE ts_1 STORAGE DISK;
alter table SendingTo TABLESPACE ts_1 STORAGE DISK;
alter table Sensor TABLESPACE ts_1 STORAGE DISK;
alter table SensorData TABLESPACE ts_1 STORAGE DISK;
alter table SensorType TABLESPACE ts_1 STORAGE DISK;
alter table SetupRequest TABLESPACE ts_1 STORAGE DISK;
alter table Site TABLESPACE ts_1 STORAGE DISK;
alter table SitePermit TABLESPACE ts_1 STORAGE DISK;
alter table User TABLESPACE ts_1 STORAGE DISK;
alter table UserDevice TABLESPACE ts_1 STORAGE DISK;
alter table UserRole TABLESPACE ts_1 STORAGE DISK;
```

Then I run the application overnight to see how the data stack.

I run the following query to see how is the table usage.

```
    SELECT sum(round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2)) `Size in MB` 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
ORDER BY (data_length + index_length) DESC;
```

It show is 1579MB

Then I calculate the In-memory usage of the data node.

In ndb_mgm, i use  `all report mem`

```
Node 11: Data usage is 41%(31826 32K pages of total 76800)
Node 11: Index usage is 47%(36148 8K pages of total 76832)
Node 12: Data usage is 41%(31822 32K pages of total 76800)
Node 12: Index usage is 47%(36123 8K pages of total 76832)

31826 * 32 /1024 + 31822 * 32 / 1024 = 1986MB
```

Seem the data is not storing in the tablespace.
Do anyone know? Thanks.